# Can course salt melt into water

Tags: solutions, phase

*What can cause course salt to melt? If you put it on a flat surface, can it melt on its own into water? What causes this reaction to make the salt melt?*

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. Please also clarify to me what course salt is?

Answer (score 2):

Salts can't "melt" at room temperature, much less into a water solution. What might happen for some salts is that they're able to draw humidity from the environment with such avidity that they become a liquid solution. If a compund can do this we call it deliquescent.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy#Deliquescence